# Off topic closing reasons

Tags: support, close-reasons

I'm just curious to why, when closing a question, for some of them I see the reason "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" and for other questions it doesn't.

Here is an example.
[How to validate quantity being added to cart from frontend?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/19168/146) - this one has 'This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network'.  Chosen at random (please don't close it unless you have a legit reason)

[system.xml field dependency](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/9935/146) - this one doesn't.  (this one is mine, but the fact that is mine has nothing to do with it. I've seen it on others.)

Comment: Example? Have you flagged the question which was not closed?

Comment: @Tim. Example added. I didn't flag any of the questions in the example.

Comment: I wonder the too. @rcartaino?

Comment: anything to do with the tags?

Comment: @DavidManners. I have no idea. I wasn't able to find a pattern.